# JAVA : How to create a snake shape matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Hi I am trying to create a matrix on the console using 2D array. The idea is that the output should look like this one :

```
1|8|9 |16
2|7|10|15
3|6|11|14
4|5|12|13
```

Is there any one who has an idea how it can be done?

Comment: Tag is as homework and don't expect people to solve it for you. What have you tried?

Comment: You need at last 2 for-loops. What have you tried?

Comment: I guess, it can be solved with one `for` loop and a couple of `if` statements

Comment: @Tomas The [homework] tag [is now deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated), but we still need to know what's been tried. A bit of context could help too.

Comment: You want to create the matrix in memory, display it somewhere?

Comment: @svz.. It will require two nested loops. One for going upwards and one for goind downwards.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve it. I spend whole day thinking about it. still noting. I will be tankful even if some one give me only a direction.

Comment: @RohitJan, you can iterate over numbers (in this case they are sequential) and choose the direction depending on which section of the *snake* you are in. It's not so neat, but still possible :)

Comment: @svz.. Yeah, if OP just wants to print them, then it will work. But in case, he needs to create a Matrix. He would need nested loops. But we can consider both the options./

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Few things** you can guess from the matrix: -

- First, you have to traverse all rows of a columns first before moving to the next column
- Second, you need to alternate between `downwards` and `upwards` direction on each iteration
- So, you would need **two nested for loop**, for iterating through rows for a particular column. One will go from `row 0 to max - 1`, and the next will go from `row = max - 1 to 0`.
- Now, to alternate the iteration direction, you can use a boolean variable, and toggle it after each iteration of inner loop finishes.
- Each loop needs to be enclosed inside an `if-else`. Both of them will be executed on a certain condition. If `boolean downwards = false;`, then loop moving upwards will be executed and vice-versa.
- On each iteration, fill the current cell with an integer counter, that you would have to initialize with `1`, and increment it after each fill.

---

**Pseudo code : -**

```
    // Initialize variables row, col, and count = 1

    boolean goDown = true;

    int[][] matrix = new int[row][col];  // declare matrix

    for i = 0 to col:
        if (goDown)
            for j = 0 to row:  // Move in downwards direction
                assign count++ to matrix[j][i] 
                // assign to `[j][i]` because, we have to assign to rows first

            goDown = false;    // Toggle goDown

        else
            for j = row - 1 to 0:  // Move in upwards direction
                assign count++ to matrix[j][i] 

            goDown = true;  // toggle goDown

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some psuedo-code, hope it helps and gives you something to start with.

```
boolean goUp = false;
boolean goDown = true;
size = 4;
matrix[size][size];
k = 0; 
l =0;

loop i->0 i < size*size i++
  matrix[l][k] = i;

  if(l==size and goDown)
    goDown = false;
    goUp = true;
    k++;
  else if(l==0 and goUp)
    goDown = true;
    goUp = false;
    k++;
  else
    l = l+ (1*goDown?1:-1);
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

finally with your help and after looking carefully at how multidimensional arrays work I solved the problem which now is looking quite simple to me.

```
int a = 4;
    int b = 4;
    int c = 1;
    boolean direction = true;
    int[][] arrey = new int[a][b];
    for (int y = 0; y <= b - 1; y++) {
        if (direction) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= a - 1; x++) {
                arrey[x][y] = c;
                c++;
            }
            direction = false;
        } else {
            for (int x = a - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
                arrey[x][y] = c;
                c++;
            }
            direction = true;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x <= a - 1; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= b - 1; y++) {
            System.out.print("["+arrey[x][y]+"]");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: Good that you successfully converted my pseudo code to real code. :)

Comment: But ideally you should accept the answer which helped you get to this solution. But again, that's all your choice. You can always post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: Because accepting the answer that helped you is a thanks giving to the post. I'm telling this for your benefit only. Not that I would get reps for that. But suppose you keep on doing this on SO, at some time, you will stop receiving good response to your answers.

Comment: Also, please don't take my comments as offend. It's not that you should not answer your question and accept that. If any question of yours is not answered clearly, and you get some better answer on yourself somewhere, then in that case you can post it and accept it. That would be fair, and we also encourage it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const matrix = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16],
];

let i = 1;

for (let col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
  if (col % 2 === 1) {
    for (let row = matrix.length - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
      matrix[row][col] = i++;
    }
  } else {
    for (let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
      matrix[row][col] = i++;
    }
  }
}

console.table(matrix);
```